# Index and Rindex in Perl

Tags: perl, indexing

I confused with Index and Rindex while writing  perl script.What is the difference between between Index and Rindex in Perl(explain with simple example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
perl -E 'say rindex("bar foo bar foo", "foo")'
                                 ^__ found first substring from right side
12

perl -E 'say index("bar foo bar foo", "foo")'
                        ^__ found first substring from left side
4
```

Comment: please comment down votes

Comment: what is the difference between of both?

Comment: here we must declare substring ?

Comment: @user3098497 in both cases you're searching for substring `foo` within  `bar foo bar foo` string. `rindex` only starts with search from right side of the string.

Comment: u mean in `reindex` we must declare substring.right?

Comment: @user3098497 what do you mean?

Comment: i mean in `rindex` we must declare `substring(foo)`?

Comment: @user3098497 in above example string is first parameter: `"bar foo bar foo"` and substring is second parameter: `"foo"` to `rindex()`